# Polyline for distance covered and actual distance :ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location, mkpolyline

Is there any way to draw a polyline with source and destination point and then have another polyline for distance covered.

I have drawn the dotted polyline for actual route but could not found a way to draw the another line for distance covered. I can plot the annotation marker for current location on route but also change the color of polyline for distance covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these I was drawing two different lines, one using direction and another using the ployline I can set title properties and check overlay.title, following code did the trick.

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView  rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
[self resetTimer];
if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKTileOverlay class]]) {
    return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
}else if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
    MKPolylineRenderer* renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyline*)overlay];
    if([overlay.title isEqualToString:@"MyLine"]) {
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [renderer setLineWidth:3.0];

        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }else{
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [renderer setLineWidth:4.0];
        [renderer setLineDashPattern:@[@2, @5]];
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    return renderer;
}
return nil;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136) is a tutorial how to add distance polyline to a mapView. Hope this helps!

Comment: The link is broken, its not opening.